# How to fix floating header

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, elementor

I've finished my website and everything, but I'm having trouble with the floating header on top, which, as you can see in the image, takes up half of the page. Apart from pages, you are unable to click on certain parts of the website since they cover the 'view cart option' and block it immediately.

[image]

I have found that "LA-Studio Element Kit for Elementor" making this mess but when I deactivate the plugin, its break my site and entire design of the site.

I also asked about this problem with Elementor support and they suggested "You should add a background color to the navigation and add a margin-top to the first sections of the page. The sticky menu section/header will cover the page as it has a position fixed" Elementor is bit difficult to understand so i dont get it. Is there any solution for it. Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to put/display that floating header to start with ?

Comment: I think if you see my website - mitaharaa.com then you'll see that the floating header is present in the entire website.